# VK api - Как скрыть статус "online" авторизированного пользователя?

Tags: vkontakte-api, android-vksdk

Есть приложение под Android для работы с `VKontakte. В нем происходит авторизация по средствам VK SDK. При этом статус авторизированного пользователя - "online". Каким образом можно реализовать так называемую "невидимку" (статус пользователя "offline" когда пользователь авторизирован и находиться в приложении)?
Единственное, что приходит в голову - написать свои хранимые процедуры, в которых будут обрабатываться запросы к VKontakte API и работать уже с ними.
Правильное ли это решение или есть другие способы?

Comment: https://vk.com/dev/account.setOffline
Вроде это должно помочь.

Comment: @Hardc0re В документации к данному методу написано следующее: "Помечает текущего пользователя как offline (**только в текущем приложении**).", поэтому данный способ не подойдет, к сожалению.

Comment: @Вадим, подойдет. Это значит, что если другое приложение изменит статус пользователя на "онлайн", то вы ничего не сможете с этим поделать. Обычного такого не происходит, поэтому из-за конфликта приложений переживать не стоит.

Comment: @Hardc0re Вы были правы. Спасибо за помощь, оформите Ваш комментарий как ответ, помечу его решением.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

https://vk.com/dev/account.setOffline

Помечает текущего пользователя как offline (только в текущем приложении).